# hide div where class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to hide the div using jQuery

I've tried the following

```
$('.field-item div.class:contains(Country||count||family)').css('display', 'none');
```

not happen.

My  html code is as follows

```
<div class="field-item">
    <div class="family">@types.family</div>
    <div class="name">@types.name</div>
    <div class="Count">@types.Count</div>
    <div class="Country">@types.Country</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not this CSS query `$('.field-item div.Country, .field-item div.count, .field-item div.family)'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains) is used to filter based on the text content of an element

Looks like you are trying to hide 3 divs then use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('.field-item').children('.Country, .Count, .family').hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jx2Bv/)

Comment: `children` would be faster I guess.

Comment: @BramVanroy yes it will be